# How can I transfer data from JSON file to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

My JSON File is like

```
{ "A": ["Apple"], 
  "B": ["Ball"], 
  "C": ["Cat"], 
  "D": ["Dog"], 
  "E": ["Elephant"], 
  "F": ["Frog"], 
  "G": ["Got"], 
}
```

When I give input-->> ABC in text Box then result will be like

> Apple
>   Ball
>   Cat

What can be done?

Comment: The obvious answer is: "yes"

Comment: https://www.google.co.za/search?q=Is+it+possible+to+build+SPA(single+page+application)+using+PHP%2B+AngularJs%3F&oq=Is+it+possible+to+build+SPA(single+page+application)+using+PHP%2B+AngularJs%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.495j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please be more explicit with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel you do like this way.
`return response()->json($data);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it like:

For sending data in JSON format with PHP, you use:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo json_encode($array);
```

To receive data in JSON format with PHP, you use:

```
$data = $_GET["x"]; // or
$data = $_POST["x"];
$result = json_decode($data);
```

Hope that can help.